# execute batch file when dropped in a specific folder

Tags: powershell, batch-file, actionlistener

I have a need to execute a batch file when I drop it into a specific folder of one of my Windows PCs.

We have 20 PCs spread out thruout the US.  I can remote into each PC and execute the batch file on the local PC but that takes a long time.

I can also do a file transfer into each of these PCs very quickly.  If I can get the batch file to execute once it is placed in a specific folder that would solve my problem.

I've heard of listeners in the past.  Where "something" on the PC is just looking at the contents of a folder.  If a file happens to exist in that folder the listener executes "something".

Here's some pseudocode to help get a better understanding:

```
\\Program watches the contents of C:\Folder1
If 
   file batchfile.bat exists in C:\Folder1
     then execute batchfile.bat and then delete batchfile.bat

Else
   continue watching C:\Folder1 for batchfile.bat
```

I'm digging around SO and looks like PowerShell is going to be the path I need to take. Do you guys agree or is there a more efficient solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
param([switch]$install)

$batchfile = "C:\Folder1\batchfile.bat"

if($install)
{
    invoke-expression ("schtasks -create -tn `"Job1`" -tr `"powershell -file '" + $myinvocation.mycommand.path + "'`" -sc DAILY -st 05:00 -rl HIGHEST -ru SYSTEM")
}
else
{
    if(test-path $batchfile)
    {
        cmd /c batchfile.bat
        remove-item $batchfile | out-null
    }
}
```

Run the above script with the "-install" switch and it will create a scheduled task to run once a day at 5:00am. If you'd like it to run more often check the syntax for [schtasks](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/schtasks.mspx?mfr=true) to change that.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure powershell is not what you are looking for. While I would recommend powershell in place of batch for your payload, it is not ideal for these kinds of scheduled tasks.

Instead I would recommend one two paths:

- If you can live with a delay, a batch or powershell script can be run every so often that checks a given folder, and runs anything it finds.
- If you want instant gratification, a Windows service is the way to go, as it will run all the time and can easily handle the listener in this fashion.